# Cannot detect a change in radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, jsfiddle

I am trying to detect a change of a radio button values so I can disable or enable a text box.

[Here is an jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6y57482x/) about it.

When The answers are respectively `Yes` and `No`, nothing happened.

Here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

$("#input[id=clinic_staff]").change(function()
{
  var clinic_staff = $('input[id=clinic_staff]:checked').val();
  var y_staff = $('input[id=y_staff]:checked').val();
  var m_staff = $('input[id=m_staff]:checked').val();
  console.log(clinic_staff);
  console.log(m_staff);
  if(clinic_staff == "Yes" && m_staff == "No")
  {
    $("#patient_name_en").val("Confidential");
    $("#patient_name_en").prop("disabled", true);
  }
  else
  {
    $("#patient_name_en").val("");
    $("#patient_name_en").prop("disabled", false);
  }
})
});
```

And the html is here:

```
<div class="col-sm-3" style="border: 1px solid">
    <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="clinic_staff" id="clinic_staff" value="Yes">Yes
    <br>
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="clinic_staff" id="clinic_staff"    value="No">No
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3" style="border: 1px solid">
    <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="m_staff" id="m_staff" value="Yes">Yes
    <br>
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="m_staff" id="m_staff"    value="No">No
</div>
<input class="form-control" type="text"  name="patient_name_en" id="patient_name_en">
```

Even I can't see the results at the console with no errors.

I tried to use:

```
$("#input[id=clinic_staff]:radio").on('change', function(){ //... });
```

And then:

```
$("#input[id=clinic_staff]:checked").on('change', function(){ //... });
```

Comment: Do `[id="clinic_staff"]` instead of `[id=clinic_staff]`. Add quotations.

Comment: An element's `id` attribute has to be unique. You can not have multiple elements with `id="clinic_staff"`. Also your jQuery selector is invalid. Instead of `#input` you need `input`

Comment: @MrGeek while better practice, that makes no difference if the value doesn't have a space or invalid character in it

Comment: Aside from the duplicate `id` attributes, remove `#` from the `#input[...` selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. You cannot use the same `id` on more than one element in the document.
2. Your selector `#input[id=clinic_staff]` will never match anything, because it's looking for an element with `id="input"` (`#input`) **and** `id="clinic_staff"` (`[id=clinic_staff]`), which naturally cannot be simultaneously true. The tag selector is just the tag name (`input`), not `#input`.

Instead, remove the `id`s and look them up a different way, perhaps `input[name=clinic_staff]`:

```
$("input[name=clinic_staff]").on("change", ...)
```

Reduced example:

```js
$("input[name=clinic_staff]").on("change", function() {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="clinic_staff" value="Yes">Yes
    <br>
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="clinic_staff" value="No">No
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: Strongly recommend use of the `label` element to make it possible to choose those radio buttons by clicking their text. My preferred way to do that is by putting the `input` *inside* the `label`:

```js
$("input[name=clinic_staff]").on("change", function() {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<div>
    <label><input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="clinic_staff" value="Yes">Yes</label>
    <br>
    <label><input type="radio" class="radio" name="clinic_staff" value="No">No</label>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...but if they have to be separate (as is often the case), you'll have to give them unique `id`s and use `for` on the label, like this:

```js
$("input[name=clinic_staff]").on("change", function() {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="clinic_staff" id="clinic_staff1" value="Yes"><label for="clinic_staff1">Yes</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="clinic_staff" id="clinic_staff2" value="No"><label for="clinic_staff2">No</label>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use it like that

```
$('input[type=radio][name=clinic_staff]').change(function()  //use it with name

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {

    $("input").on('change', function()
    {
      var clinic_staff = $('#clinic_staff:checked').val();
      var m_staff = $('#m_staff:checked').val();
      console.log(clinic_staff);
      console.log(m_staff);
      if(clinic_staff == "Yes" && m_staff == "No")
      {
        $("#patient_name_en").val("Confidential");
        $("#patient_name_en").attr("disabled", true);
      }
      else
      {
        $("#patient_name_en").val("");
        $("#patient_name_en").attr("disabled", false);
      }
    })
 });
```

A free downvote means explanation required, got it.

First of all, `$("#input[id=clinic_staff]")`. In jQuery, `#` means that it's getting the id of some field. There you're trying to get something with both id=input and id=clinic_staff. Something impossible, like some people have already said. `$('input[id=m_staff]:checked')` is much better, but all has to be said, jQuery exists to make your life easier. You could simply write `$('#m_staff:checked')` there.

Another thing: I made it more responsive, making it execute the function every time you check another button. I did it because if somebody chooses "Yes" in the first one and then "No" in the second one, it wouldn't show the "Confidential" tag, because you were making it only respond to events on the first radio buttons.

Third but this is less important: I changed it back to `$("input").on('change', function()`. This is just because I use it this way, so feel free to do as you wish there hahah.

I add here the snippet in case you want to test it.

```html
<div class="col-sm-3" style="border: 1px solid">
    <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="clinic_staff" id="clinic_staff" value="Yes">Yes
    <br>
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="clinic_staff" id="clinic_staff"    value="No">No
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3" style="border: 1px solid">
    <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="m_staff" id="m_staff" value="Yes">Yes
    <br>
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="m_staff" id="m_staff"    value="No">No
</div>
<input class="form-control" type="text"  name="patient_name_en" id="patient_name_en">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
  {

    $("input").on('change', function()
    {
      var clinic_staff = $('#clinic_staff:checked').val();
      var m_staff = $('#m_staff:checked').val();
      //console.log(clinic_staff);
      //console.log(m_staff);
      if(clinic_staff == "Yes" && m_staff == "No")
      {
        $("#patient_name_en").val("Confidential");
        $("#patient_name_en").attr("disabled", true);
      }
      else
      {
        $("#patient_name_en").val("");
        $("#patient_name_en").attr("disabled", false);
      }
    })
 });

</script>
```